# Kendo Grid: How to set focus back to a grid cell after canceling current editing

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am looking at how to override some of the default keyboard commands for the Kendo grid. As in my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/j208tuen/1/), and am intercepting the enter key, and want to move down a cell as done in the following block of code..

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
      var current = grid.current();
      var index = current.index();
      var next = $(current).closest('tr').next('tr');                    

      var td = next.find('td:eq(' + index + ')');
      grid.closeCell();
      grid.current(td);  
      current = grid.current();
      grid.focus(current);
      //current.focus();
      return;
    }
```

It is very close to working. If I am in navigation mode before I hit enter then all still works fine. However, if I am in an **edit** mode (eg tab to a cell and then hit enter) , it does go down a cell and back to navigation mode, however I don't seem to have the correct focus. The left right arrow keys don't work, and up an down arrows seem to show focus is on the page, not within the grid.

I have tried calling the focus in various ways, but I just can't get it working. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set focus on the table itself because the grid's keydown event handler is bound to the table:

```
scope.$on("kendoRendered", function (e) {
    var grid = scope.grid;
    var elem = $(grid.table);

    // attach keydown handler to the table
    var newHandler = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
            var current = grid.current();
            var index = current.index();
            var next = $(current).closest('tr').next('tr');

            grid.closeCell();
            var td = next.find('td:eq(' + index + ')');

            grid.current(td);
            $(td).closest("table").focus();
        }
    };

    $(elem).on("keydown", newHandler);
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p6womgL9/1/))

Comment: I Just tried  small extension of this, that I thought would be the same - I wanted to do this also with the arrow keys (I assumed would be the same as entered), but for some reason the combo handles the key first, so that just before we go to the new cell, the combo value changes Here (http://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/p6womgL9/2/) I have handled the down arrow (will be doing up arrow as well). Is there a way to stop this happening for the arrow keys (I wonder why they are different to the enter). Cheers

Comment: you'd have to disable keyboard navigation for the widget; http://jsfiddle.net/p6womgL9/4/